# Cannot run app pool as service account

Tags: python, iis

I had a Python Flask website that ran fine when I ran the app pool as my own account. When I tried changing this to a service account (which should have permissions), I get the following error

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
>
> The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has
>   occurred.
>
> Most likely causes: •IIS received the request; however, an internal
>   error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of
>   this error depends on which module handles the request and what was
>   happening in the worker process when this error occurred. •IIS was not
>   able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application.
>   This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly. •IIS was
>   not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
>   •The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL. •The
>   request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility
>   Feature is not installed.
>
> Detailed Error Information: Module    FastCgiModule
>
> Notification    ExecuteRequestHandler
>
> Handler    Python Flask
>
> Error Code    0x80070542
>
> Requested URL    http://qatools:80/
>
> Physical Path    D:\PythonWebService\QATools
>
> Logon Method    Anonymous
>
> Logon User    Anonymous

If I change it back to run as my own account, it works. Any thoughts?

Comment: As the handler Flask reports this error, you should report to its developers or search their archive.

Comment: You need to give the service account permission in the file system to access the folder(s)/files in which your webapp lives.

Answer (score 0):

FYI after some tinkering, I changed the app pool to run with Managed Pipeline mode of "Classic" instead of "Integrated" and it worked.